# 64bit precision Sleep function?

Tags: c, winapi, timer, sleep

Currently [Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) takes a single DWORD (32bit) for time. Is there any alternative which takes DWORDLONG (64bit)?

I'm using RNG in which with every additional byte added the overall wait time increases. With 32bit integer the overall time is 5 minutes and I want to increase it.

Comment: No, but why would you want to sleep longer than 49.7 days?

Comment: well, it's restful, for starters

Comment: Windows doesn't hold that long without rebooting/crashing/getting forceful updates.

Comment: @GovindParmar I'm using randomly generated bytes from random.org and is unlikely they will reach the top but with a higher precision the overall wait time will be longer

Comment: I didn't get the connection to `random.org`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's that with a higher precision the overall wait time will be longer I don't expect to hit the highest number every-time. The overall wait time for 32bit is like maybe 5 minutes.

Comment: `NtDelayExecution` take `PLARGE_INTEGER DelayInterval` so 64 bit value. which also can be absolute or relative (from current time)

Comment: How is it related to precision? Are you looking for `sleep` with higher *resolution* ? Like taking microseconds rather than milliseconds?

Comment: You're scraping [https://www.random.org/bytes/](https://www.random.org/bytes/) to get an RNG that you then use to call the Windows [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) API?

Comment: @txtechhelp What's wrong with that?

Comment: That just seems a bit excessive, and to what end? As others have pointed out, _why_ do you want to halt your thread for that long versus using an event driven system, like with conditional variables and callbacks ... And why are you scraping a web api to get an RNG, would a PRNG not work for your purpose? Lastly, if you are scraping the site, I'm pretty sure you can set how many bytes you want back, so specifying 4 bytes would make sure you don't exceed your `DWORD` value.

Comment: It sounds more and more like some crazy XY-problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Sleep[Ex]` internal call [`NtDelayExecution`](https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FThread%2FNtDelayExecution.html) - undocumented but exist in all windows nt versions (from nt 4 to win 10) - exported by *ntdll.dll* - use *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib* from wdk. as result of this call in kernel will be called documented function [`KeDelayExecutionThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-kedelayexecutionthread)

```
//extern "C"
NTSYSAPI 
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtDelayExecution(
  IN BOOLEAN              Alertable,
  IN PLARGE_INTEGER       Interval );
```

> - **Alertable**
>
> Specifies **TRUE** if the wait is alertable. Lower-level drivers should
> specify **FALSE**.
>
> - **Interval**
>
> Specifies the absolute or relative time, in units of 100 nanoseconds,
> for which the wait is to occur. A negative value indicates relative
> time. Absolute expiration times track any changes in system time;
> relative expiration times are not affected by system time changes.

`Sleep[Ex]` is win32 shell, over this native api, which restrict interval value (from 64 to 32 bit) can not set absolute time (possible with `NtDelayExecution`) and ignore alerts (we can exit from NtDelayExecution via alert thread if wait alertable)

so you can direct call this api instead indirect via `Sleep[Ex]`

so `Sleep(dwMilliseconds)` is call `SleepEx(dwMilliseconds, false)`

```
SleepEx(dwMilliseconds, bAlertable)
```

call

```
LARGE_INTEGER  Interval;
Interval.QuadPart = -(dwMilliseconds * 10000);
NtDelayExecution(bALertable, &Interval);
```

note that in case alertable wait it can be broken via apc (api return `STATUS_USER_APC`) or via alert ( `STATUS_ALERTED` will be returned. we can alert thread via `NtAlertThread`). the `SleepEx` check returned status and in case `STATUS_ALERTED` - again begin wait with updated interval. so `SleepEx` wait can not be broken via alert (`NtAlertThread`) but `NtDelayExecution` can

Comment: What does negative value means again?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - negative value means relative time. so exactly which `Sleep` use only 64 bit. say if you want wait 1 second - set `DelayInterval.QuadPart = -10000000` if want wait infinite - `DelayInterval.QuadPart = 0x8000000000000000`

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - in any case in kernel finally called documented function [`KeDelayExecutionThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-kedelayexecutionthread) - read here about `Interval` parameter

Comment: Btw what are you saying about APC - I'm specifying bAlertable to be false. Also what's the difference between KeDelayExecutionThread and ZwDelayExecution?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - if you set `bAlertable` to false - your wait can not be broken by apc or alert (this is not apc). `NtDelayExecution` in user mode - this is stub for  `NtDelayExecution` in kernel mode. this api call `KeDelayExecutionThread`. look https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ex/delay.c

Answer (score 2):

`Sleep()` takes milliseconds. The max `DWORD` value, 4294967295, will result in a timeout period of 49.7 days. For most purposes, that's a good enough maximum value, but if you're that determined to have a 64-bit sleep parameter, you can chain multiple `Sleep()` calls together. This will change the maximum number of milliseconds that you can `Sleep()` for to 18446744073709551615, which is roughly 600 million years:

```
VOID WINAPI Sleep64(DWORDLONG dwlMilliseconds)
{
    while (dwlMilliseconds)
    {
        DWORD dwSleepTime = min(0xFFFFFFFE, dwlMilliseconds);
        Sleep(dwSleepTime);
        dwlMilliseconds -= dwSleepTime;
    }
}
```

I have tested this and can verify that it works.

Comment: How long did you test it for? :)

Comment: So was mine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any alternative which takes DWORDLONG (64bit)?

No. You'll need multiple calls to `Sleep`, in a loop.

Have fun testing and debugging multi-month sleep.

Comment: or call `NtDelayExecution`

Comment: Argh, there's always an undocumented API that you know about, @RbMm ;-)

Comment: but `Sleep[Ex]` internal call `NtDelayExecution`. this is win32 shell over this native api which restrict interval value (from 64 to 32 bit) can not set absolute time (possible with `NtDelayExecution`) and ignore alerts (we can exit from `NtDelayExecution` via alert thread if wait alertable)

Comment: @RbMm I guess you didn't appreciate my humour. Oh well.

Comment: sorry. simply dont know what need say here :)